# How to configure the same binding for multiple Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have 10 Azure Functions with the same binding (each in a separate project):

```cs
// In Employee project

[FunctionName("EmployeeEventConsumer")]
public async Task Run(
    [KafkaTrigger("%Kafka:BootstrapServers%", "%Kafka:Topic%",
        ConsumerGroup = "%Kafka:ConsumerGroup%",
        Protocol = BrokerProtocol.SaslSsl,
        AuthenticationMode = BrokerAuthenticationMode.Plain,
        Username = "%Kafka:SaslUsername%",
        Password = "%Kafka:SaslPassword%",
        SslCaLocation = "%Kafka:SslCaLocation%"
    )]
    KafkaEventData<string, string>[] kafkaEvents, FunctionExecutionContext executionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Handle(kafkaEvents, executionContext, cancellationToken);
}
```

Difference is only in configurations values (`Kafka:Topic`).

Is it possible to not duplicate `KafkaTrigger` attribute values each time, and just configure all my Azure Function to use the same one?

PS: I know, it's a very small issue, but my organization has a SonarCloud set up and it forbids me from completing PR if I don't remove duplicated code

Comment: just deploy the same function 10 times which diffrent settings?!

Comment: @silent Not all code is the same, just the trigger. Messages from different topics have different structure and need to be processed slightly differently (but most of the code is the same, and abstracted into the common project)